# Make File not being able to link c++ even though .o files are there

Tags: c++, makefile, linker

So I have a make file that compiles 3 different files for a hash map. One file is an entry in the hash map, one file is the hash map itself and one file is my main file. I can compile each file individually fine, but when I try to compile and link the main file it says that my references to my Hashtable class are undefined, even though I included the header for that class in the main file.

Here's my make file:

```
all: project1

project1:
    g++ -o project1 main.cpp HashTable.cpp HashEntry.cpp -g -Wall

main.o: HashTable.o
    g++ -c -Wall -g main.cpp

HashTable.o: HashEntry.o
    g++ -c -Wall -g HashTable.cpp

HashEntry.o:
    g++ -c -Wall -g HashEntry.cpp

clean:
    rm *.o
```

I tried looking around other places but didn't see a situation that I haven't covered. What else could be wrong in the code? I've tried using .o for the files in the project1 command too.

Here's the main class code. It is complaining about any time I reference HashTable (lines 24, 45, 53, 57 says there's an undefined reference)

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include "HashTable.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    std::vector<std::string> keyList;
    std::ifstream inputFile(argv[1]);
    int numInputs = 0;
    std::string line;
    if(inputFile.is_open()){
        while(getline(inputFile,line)){
            std::stringstream currLine(line);
            numInputs++;
            std::string textCatch;
            getline(currLine,textCatch,',');
            keyList.push_back(textCatch);
        }
    }
    inputFile.close();

    HashTable *dataTable = new HashTable(numInputs);

    std::ifstream secondPass(argv[1]);
    if(secondPass.is_open()){
        while(getline(secondPass,line)){
            std::stringstream currLine(line);
            std::string field;
            int value1;
            int value2;
            getline(currLine, field, ',');
            std::string key = field;
            getline(currLine, field, ',');
            std::istringstream convert(field);
            if(!(convert >> value1)){
                value1 = NULL;
            }
            getline(currLine, field);
            std::istringstream convert2(field);
            if(!(convert2 >> value2)){
                value2 = NULL;
            }
            dataTable->put(key,value1,value2);
        }
    }
    secondPass.close();

    std::ofstream outputFile("output.dat");
    for(int i = 0; i < keyList.size(); i++){
        std::string key = keyList[i];
        double average = dataTable->getAverage(key);
        std::ostringstream stringStream;
        stringStream << average;
        std::string avgString = stringStream.str();
        int max = dataTable->getMax(key);
        stringStream << max;
        std::string maxString = stringStream.str();
        outputFile << key + " | " + avgString + " | " + maxString;
    }
    outputFile.close();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your makefile is obviously broken. Only the first target is ever used, which will always compile and link the three cpp files from source, every time. That's not what a makefile is for. However that may not necessarily have anything to do with your issue. This question cannot be answered without a [mcve] in terms of the contents of each relevant file, here. You need to edit your question, and add a [mcve].

Comment: Why use a Makefile explicitly and not e.g. CMake in 2016?

Comment: Because it's required to use a makefile for our assignment because our professor is stubborn to change. Also, updated the OP to show my main class

Comment: So it worked when I changed my include from the header file to the .cpp file itself.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was fixed when I changed the include from "HashTable.h" to "HashTable.cpp"

For some reason I thought the .h would be enough for the linker to know to find the implementation of the methods in the other file, but I guess it wasn't (And now that I think about it, it makes sense that it doesn't).

Comment: Your Makefile could look [something like this](http://pastebin.com/yQMsUHDy). It could be even shorter if you want to just use *implicit rules*. An excellent online reference to Gnu make [can be found here](https://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/make-3.79.1/html_chapter/make_toc.html). Best of luck.

Comment: That's a very bad solution. Instead of fixing your makefile or learning to use the linker correctly, you've kludged your sourcefiles in a way that throws away the advantages of having object files.